# How to plot the 10^30 as the point of X axis in Logarithmic chart by using Plotly.Blazor

Tags: plotly, blazor

I want to create a graph with the logarithmic x-axis and scatter y-axis using Plotly.Blazor NuGet. The x-axis range is 10^0 to 10^100 and the step size is 10^10. I have to plot 10 points with x-axis values like 0,10^10,10^20,10^30.. so on. I took random scatter values for the y-axis. I can plot the x-axis point till 10^29. But I am unable to plot an x-axis point more than 10^29. I got some exceptions when I try to plot the 10^30 as an x-axis point. Is any way available to plot the x-axis points till 10^100?

I got this below exception

[image]

When I run the below code

MainLayout.razor.cs

```
 public partial class MainLayout
{
    public static List<Series> SeriesData;
    public MainLayout()
    {
        SeriesData = new List<Series>();

        //Series - 1
        SeriesData.Add(new Series
        {
            Name = "Series 1",
            XAxis = GenerateXAxisValues(30, 0, 1),
            YAxis = GenerateYAxisValues(100, 1, 100),
            Color = "#eb4034"
        });
    }

    private static List<object> GenerateXAxisValues(double xAxisMax, double xAxisMin, double xAxisStepSize)
    {
        List<object> XAxisValue = new List<object>();
          for (double value = xAxisMin; value <  Math.Pow(10,xAxisMax); value = Math.Pow(10,xAxisStepSize++))
        {
            XAxisValue.Add(value);
        }
        return XAxisValue;
    }
    private static List<object> GenerateYAxisValues(int yAxisMax, int yAxisMin, int xAxisValueCount)
    {
        List<object> YAxisValue = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < xAxisValueCount; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int rInt = r.Next(yAxisMin, yAxisMax);
            YAxisValue.Add(rInt);
        }
        return YAxisValue;
    }
}

public class Series
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<object> XAxis { get; set; }
    public List<object> YAxis { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

PlotlyLogarithmicChart.razor.cs

```
public partial class PlotlyLogarithmicChart
{
    private Plotly.Blazor.PlotlyChart Chart;
    private Config config = new()
    {
         Responsive = true
    };

    private IList<ITrace> dataset = new List<ITrace>();

    private Layout layout = new()
    {
        ShowLegend = false,

        XAxis = new List<XAxis>
        {
   
            new XAxis()
            {
                Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.XAxisLib.Title { Text = "XAXIS" },
                Side = Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.XAxisLib.SideEnum.Bottom,
                Range = new List<object> { "0", "100" },
                Ticks= Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.XAxisLib.TicksEnum.Outside,
                DTick = "10",
                TickColor = "#000",
                TickLen = 10,
                TickWidth = 2,
                ShowTickLabels = true,
                GridWidth = 2,
                Overlaying = "x",
                ShowSpikes = true,
                SpikeDash = "dash",
                SpikeThickness = 2,
                SpikeColor = "#000",
                 Type=Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.XAxisLib.TypeEnum.Log,
                 ExponentFormat = Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.XAxisLib.ExponentFormatEnum.E,
            },
        },

        YAxis = new List<YAxis>
        {
            new YAxis()
            {
                Title = new Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.YAxisLib.Title{ Text = "YAXIS"},
                Side = Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.YAxisLib.SideEnum.Left,
                Range = new List<object> {"0", "100"},
                Ticks= Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.YAxisLib.TicksEnum.Outside,
                DTick = "10",
                TickColor = "#000",
                TickLen = 10,
                TickWidth = 2,
                ShowTickLabels = true,
                Overlaying = "y",
                GridWidth = 2,
                ShowSpikes = true,
                SpikeDash = "dash",
                SpikeThickness = 2,
                SpikeColor = "#000",
            }
        },
    };

    public MultipleAxes()
    {
        UpdateSeriesPlots(); 
    }

    private void CustomLegend(object arg, string checkedSeriesName)
    {
        foreach(var item in dataset.Select((value, index) => new { index, value }))
        {
            Scatter series = item.value as Scatter;
            if(series.Name == checkedSeriesName)
            {
                if(arg.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    series.Visible = VisibleEnum.True;
                }
                else
                {
                    series.Visible = VisibleEnum.False;
                }
                dataset[item.index] = series;
                break;
            }
        }
        Chart.React();
    }

    private void UpdateSeriesPlots()
    {
        dataset.Add(new Scatter
        {
            Name = "",
            Mode = ModeFlag.Lines | ModeFlag.Markers,
            X = new List<object> { },
            Y = new List<object> { },
            
        });

        foreach (var item in MainLayout.SeriesData)
        {
            dataset.Add(new Scatter
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                Mode = ModeFlag.Lines | ModeFlag.Markers,
                X = item.XAxis,
                Y = item.YAxis,
                XAxis = "x2",
                YAxis = "y2",
                HoverInfo = HoverInfoFlag.X | HoverInfoFlag.Y,
                Line = new Line
                {
                    Color = item.Color
                },
                HoverLabel = new Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib.HoverLabel
                {
                    BgColor = "#fcf7fc",
                    BorderColor = "#000",
                    Font = new Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib.HoverLabelLib.Font
                    {
                        Color = "#000",
                        Family = "Times New Roman",
                        Size = 16
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

PlotlyLogarithmicChart.razor

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@using Plotly.Blazor
@using Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib
@using Plotly.Blazor.Traces
@using Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib
@using System.Diagnostics
@using Blazor_Layout = Plotly.Blazor.Layout
@using Title = Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.Title
@using YAxis = Plotly.Blazor.LayoutLib.YAxis

<div style="height:500px;width:1200px;text-align:center;">
    <PlotlyChart style="height:500px;width:950px;display:inline-block" @bind-Config="config" @bind-Layout="layout" @bind-Data="dataset" @ref="Chart"/>
    <div style="height:500px;width:200px;display:inline-block;top:0px;vertical-align:top">
        @foreach (var item in MainLayout.SeriesData)
        {
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" @onchange="a => { CustomLegend(a.Value, item.Name);}" checked > 
                <label style="background-color:@item.Color; margin:5px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">@item.Name</label>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please share some code and the exception you got?

Comment: I have added the code and exception snippet in the question itself